# node.js synchronously mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-maps, asynchronous

I am working in node.js with mySql database.

i'm fetching lat-long routes from googleMaps sanpToRoad Api and insert that data into my table but it's doesn't inserted in flow (sequence)

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'root',
    password        : '',
    database        : 'myTestDb'
});


var googleAPILink = 'https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path='+lastLat+','+lastLong+'|'+currentLat+','+currentLong+'&interpolate=true&key=GOOGLE_MAP_KEY';

console.log(googleAPILink);

var roadResponse = request(googleAPILink, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        responseData = JSON.parse(body);


        for(i = 0; i < responseData.snappedPoints.length; i++) {

            var locationArrayObject = responseData.snappedPoints[i];

            var locationArrayObjectInsider = (locationArrayObject.location);

            var roadLat = locationArrayObjectInsider.latitude;

            var roadLong = locationArrayObjectInsider.longitude

            var rideStatus = rows2[0].status;

            var rideStartedAns = 'n';

            if(rideStatus == 's')
            {
                rideStartedAns = 'y'
            }



            var post  = {
                            tripid: rideId,
                            latitude: roadLat, 
                            road_longitude: roadLong,
                            rideStarted: rideStartedAns,
                            routeRideCounter: routeCounter,
                            status: 'y'
                        };



            pool.getConnection(function(err, connectDB4) {

                var qry = connectDB4.query('INSERT INTO tbl_rout SET ?', post, function(err5, result5) {
                    console.log(qry.sql);
                    connectDB4.release();
                });
            });
        }

    }
});
```

So, here if google Maps API return me in lat-long routes sequence like

1)

lat : 12.3456789,
long : 12.3456789

2)

lat : 23.1456789,
long : 23.1456789

3)

lat : 34.1256789,
long : 34.1256789

then it will may be first insert record 3) then may be insert record 1) then may be insert record 2).

so it will conflict my code and i can't get proper flow of map road path.

please help me.

Comment: I think the problem is you are mixing async code with sync one. Each iteration of your for loop is firing an `INSERT` query and you are using the `post` object created in for loop directly in the callback, there is no guarantee what values `post` will hold because your insert query is async, there is no way to know when it will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is your for loop flush all the requests together. Using this technique you cant get control the query execution flow.

There are two ways to achieve this

1. Dont call insert query in a loop. prepare a query for example 
      INSERT INTO tableName(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(val1,val2,val3),             (val1,val2,val3),.... 
   create  query like this and execute it once this will do it in one db call   instead of many
2. Second way is to use async module
   async.eachSeries will execute you query one by one instead of flushing and this will enter data in sequence. check example below.

   ```
       do npm install async --save

       var async = require('async');

       async.eachSeries(responseData.snappedPoints , function(snappedPoint , cb){
       var locationArrayObject = snappedPoint;

       var locationArrayObjectInsider = (locationArrayObject.location);

       var roadLat = locationArrayObjectInsider.latitude;

       var roadLong = locationArrayObjectInsider.longitude

       var rideStatus = rows2[0].status;

       var rideStartedAns = 'n';

       if(rideStatus == 's')
       {
           rideStartedAns = 'y'
       }



       var post  = {
                       tripid: rideId,
                       latitude: roadLat, 
                       road_longitude: roadLong,
                       rideStarted: rideStartedAns,
                       routeRideCounter: routeCounter,
                       status: 'y'
                   };



       pool.getConnection(function(err, connectDB4) {

           var qry = connectDB4.query('INSERT INTO tbl_rout SET ?', post,    function(err5, result5) {
               console.log(qry.sql);
               connectDB4.release();
               cb();
           });
       });
   }, function(){
       console.log('execuation completed);
   });
   ```